# IE11 Page name when printing

Tags: html, css, web, printing, printing-web-page

I have a print button on my web page using the code...

```
<input class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" type="button" onclick="document.title = 'callslip'; window.print()" value="Print">
```

This calls the print.css file to format the page and renames the page to callslip. This works fine in all browsers apart from IE. The name IE gies is the original name plus other additional information. 'http___localhost_3898_Job_Detail_1'.

Is there anyway to overwrite the nameing conventon for IE11?

regards,

Comment: Not by you. The owner of the browser can set (or clear) the header and footer in the page detail options.